# Pulling wrong data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have one spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LONz6rkyn4jM_aobSq1HIwjbeOXs2MhK6p_c_fNy8Wo/edit#gid=0
the column I contains formula
=VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H0g2FwZZbD6L33KOhuXakuRbWDsIWDNGburMZ3Tf4T4/edit#gid=0","Internal!$A$2:$G$1000"),7)

which is supposed to pull out data from this spreadsheet, column G
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H0g2FwZZbD6L33KOhuXakuRbWDsIWDNGburMZ3Tf4T4/edit#gid=0

For some reasons it does not pull the data in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,IMPORTRANGE("1H0g2FwZZbD6L33KOhuXakuRbWDsIWDNGburMZ3Tf4T4","Internal!A:G"),7, FALSE)))`
from [this](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/vlookup-importrange-in-google-sheets/)